Please ID this movie western featuring telescopic sight
I saw a FANTASTIC movie about 20 years ago or more, please help me ID it. Color, & I cant recall exactly if it had a 'spaghetti western' feel to it, but it was set in Mexico or the wild west. A kid of about 12 or 13 is living tough with his single mum. A traveling salesman comes through the area and one of his wares is the newly invented telescopic sight / telescopic rifle.  The kid "goes bad", steals the rifle, & embarks on a vengeful crime spree. Pretty soon this kid is running the show as the baddest person in the baddest town around. He is halled up with the girls in the bordello, running that too. Anyone in the town that gets killed gets fed to a big pig, leaving no evidence behind. It was a really great movie that has you barracking for the kid. There is a scene in it reminiscent of the Clint Eastwood movie, Unforgiven, where a specially imported gunslinger/lawman, hired to get the kid, is suddenly shot between the eyes only there is no one around but a stark flat silent horizon (no doubt the work of the kid & his telescopic rifle).

It has some things in common with Streets of Laredo, one of the sequels to Lonesome Dove. There was a young Mexican kid named Joey Garza, who kills the owner of a German rifle with a telescopic sight. He uses this to kill people from very long distances. He does become the most hunted man in the territory.
I don't remember anything about a big pig, but I actually never saw the mini-series, only read the book it was based on. 
Here is a picture of Joey Garza with the rifle:

Thank you, I think you have nailed it. I cant not find for the life of me where I 'accept' your answer. Many, many thanks.

There should be a check mark beneath the down arrow, just to the left of the answer. It is only visible to the one who asked the question (you). Glad to help with the movie.
